# How to set up a single site app catalog?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-collection, pnp-powershell, app-catalog

Can anybody point me in the right direction on how to set up an App catalog for a single site in my tenant (SharePoint online)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Catalog can be setup at **Site collection** level and not site (web)/subsite level.

You can create a site collection app catalog using SharePoint Online PowerShell.

**Example:**

```
Add-SPOSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing
```

OR

By using **PnP PowerShell**:

```
Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -site https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing
```

**Source**: [Use the site collection app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog).

Comment: Hi BennKingy, does this answer helped you? dose it answers your question?